# How To Delay A Shipment For A Week Using Shopify API?

Tags: postman, shopify, shopify-api

I am going to delay a shipment for a week using API, i used order UPDATE api `https://storename.myshopify.com/admin/api/2023-04/orders/11111111.json` with body

```
{
    "order": {
        "id": orderID,
        "fulfillment_status": "null",
        "fulfillments": [
            {
                "id": ID,
                "location_id": ID,
                "tracking_number": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                "tracking_url": "https://tools.usps.com/go/TrackConfirmAction.action?tLabels=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                "status": "delayed",
                "delayed_until": "2023-05-29T00:00:00Z"
            }
        ],
        "line_items": [
            {
                "id": ID,
                "fulfillment_status": "null"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

but it didn't work, what is the exact API and body i should use to update the order with shipment fulfillment status or any other status it would be delayed for a week.

Answer (score 0):

That call did not work primarily because you just made something up with no basis in any research of the API in question. Fair enough. If you did do some research though, you'd discover you can place a fulfillment on hold. Seems like a thing to do in this case. So place it on hold with an API call. Then, when you need to fulfill, in a week, you can issue a call to revoke the hold and deliver.